Which school is it?
Determine the hidden school thanks to:
1747 PB-OR-NI-TD-.G-.E


1st is the entry
2nd is related to 1848
3rd is a library
4th is related to 26
5th is financial
6th is related to 194
7th leads to Bob
8th is related to C
9th is nuclear


Hints

 The first hints will consist of adding items to the list

13.08.2024



 10th is a little tower



15.08.2024



 11th connects the town hall



